# Structure SQL insert Transactions for C# Parent / Child objects

Tags: c#, sql-server, parent-child, transactionscope

I'm developing some business-ware objects in C#. Each object has the ability to save itself to a associated database like such (each object):

```
public void Save()
{
    //Collect object attributes and convert to SQLParameters
    //Add SQL Parameters to SQL command and BeginTrans   
    //Execute, if No Errors, commit, otherwise rollback   
}
```

I have started implementing the inheritance/Parent child portion and I don't know how to structure the Parent Object Save() function with inner child objects because:

- Each child object has it's own Save() method with complete with associated it's own Connection, SQL 
  Command, BeginTrans, parameter logic and rollback logic etc.
- Each Object.Save() call's a specific stored procedure for that object/database type.
- **MOST IMPORTANTLY: I want the ENTIRE SAVE to roll back if any child object Save's Fail.**

For example:

- If object "Customer" has child objects "CustomerInfo", "Account" and "Dependents".
- When the Customer.Save is executed, if the save for child objects "CustomerInfo" and "Account" succeed, but then the save for child object "Dependents FAIL, then I want the previous saves to rollback up to the calling Customer Parent object.

What is the best way to do this?

I would like to keep the logic for Save (parameter formatting, execute and rollback) encapsulated within each object i.e.

Like this:

```
public void ParentSave()
{ 
   Begin Transaction

   Try
   {
   //For each CHILD Object
   //ChildObject.Save()
   }
   Catch(Save Fail)
   {
      //Rollback all executed saves/transaction(s)
    }

   IF(Success)
   {
      //Save parent
      Commit parent/overall transaction
    }
}
```

I know I could use "transaction" Scope, but I'm not sure how to structure it or if I should have "nested" transaction scopes. I have never used transaction Scope before. I know Transaction works with nested Begin/Commit transactions (true commit doesn't occur until begin trans count goes to 1), but does it work for nested transactions using their Connection/SQLCommand Object?

- Concerning "Transaction Scope": if each object has it's save within it's own encapsulated function (each object's save() starts it's own connection, SQL command, does the Begin/commit, executes, and closes the SQL command object)**
- I DO NOT want to write a specific stored procedure for each parent/child Schema (i.e. have a stored proc for each variation of Parent/child objects).
- If it was NECESSARY, I could write logic for each object to retrieve it's own SQLParameters/command info so the Parent caller could coalesce them and execute them in one big, staged transaction, but I would rather not.
- If I have to write a staged transaction, should I use "Sql SavePoints"? Why/Why Not? I'm guessing NO as if there are any errors, I'm rolling the ENTIRE thing back.
- I could pass a connection object if need be to "chain" chain these parent object saves.

Comment: Why you need to have different save methods, can you have one method which will save everything within one connection and one transaction?

Comment: If you want to put everything under one Transaction, then yes, everything needs to be in one giant method.

Comment: Another thought - if you want to encapsulate the individual saves, can you consider saving the running list of saved objects, with their unique identifiers, and then go back and remove them when a transaction down the line fails? If you are using identity columns though, you'll be leaving holes in the column owing to inserts and then deletes - not that it matters in the general sense, but something to consider.

Comment: SQL Server has no true nested transactions, save points are rarely useful, and yes, `TransactionScope` is the way to go if you don't want to burden the individual methods with transaction logic. If you close and open the same connection in a scope (as in, using the *exact* same connection string) the different `SqlConnection`s will automatically enlist in the same transaction without it becoming a distributed transaction. You don't even need explicit logic to roll back, since that will happen automatically when the scope is disposed without having seen a commit.

Comment: Fabio, To clarify, by "different save methods": I mean that all of my objects inherit from a base object that does a save according to the inherited object's schema. Each object that derives from said base can has a base save as long as it's object schema is defined. I would love to have the parent child have a save where it can iterate through each child's save method but it looks as if that is not the case.

Comment: Rakesh, that is GREAT idea. I don't have enough activity to be concerned about repetitive Inserts/Deletes and the only Table that uses an Identity Column is my SequentialGUIDs... Plus that would allow me to keep my logic for Save, Delete. Buttoned up.

Answer (score 1):

I would overload `Save` and make it a function:

```
public bool Save()
{
    //Open SqlConnection

    //Begin Transaction

    bool success = Save(cn, Trans);

    if (success)
    {
        //Commit

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //Rollback

        return false;
    }
}

public bool Save(SqlConnection cn, SqlTransaction trans)
{
    //Save self using cn and trans. If fails, immediately return false.
    //Save each child using Save(cn, trans). If any one fails, immediately return false.
    //If no failures, return true.
}
```

When you want to save an object, call `Save()` (no arguments).

`Save()` will create a new connection and transaction and then call `Save(SqlConnection cn, SqlTransaction trans)` which will attempt to save the object using the connection and transaction just created. `Save(SqlConnection cn, SqlTransaction trans)` will then recursively call itself on all child objects until everything is saved from the top down.

If anything fails at any point, `Save(SqlConnection cn, SqlTransaction trans)` will return `false` all the way back up the call stack to the initial `Save()` which will initiate the rollback. If there are no failures, it will return `true` which will trigger the commit.